# Why Concurrent HashMap is Serializable

Tags: java, serialization, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I was going through the source code of concurrent hashmap and found it is serializable. Also HashMap is serializable.

Why concurrent hashmap/hashmap is serializable? I mean why this design choice was made.

Comment: Because it implements "Serializable" interface.

Comment: Here you can get something interesting http://marxsoftware.blogspot.in/2010/10/cannot-assume-serializability-for-java.html

Comment: The Java `HashMap` class _is_ `Serializable`, q.v. [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Answer (score 3):

The HashMap is serializable, the class implements `Serializable` interface

```
public class HashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements Map<K,V>, Cloneable, Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 362498820763181265L;
```

The same is ConcurrentHashMap:

```
public class ConcurrentHashMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V>
implements ConcurrentMap<K,V>, Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7249069246763182397L;
```

you can get more detail about java serialize in the following link

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm

Comment: I think OP wanted to know why it implements Serializable interface, why this design choice was made.

Comment: We may not find satisfactory answer for your query. But I have not seen much difference between HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap Serializaiton process except for $WriteThroughEntry. Some interesting facts at : http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073605/cannot-assume-serializability-for-java-map-s-nested-classes.html

Comment: yes, I want to know why it implements Serializable interface.

Answer (score 1):

As other already said, `HashMap` is `Serializable`, but the Map or `Collection` interface doesn't force the implementation of every collection to be "serializable". If you want to create you're own `Set` or `Map` and not set it to serializable, it's your choice and it wouldn't make sense to force people to do it.

But my guess is, most utility classes like `Collection` implementations are serializable so everyone doesn't have to create their own `SerializableHashMap`, because these classes are used a lot and lots of people serialize them. So it's kinda a basic feature for them to have.

Comment: What disturbs me a lot though, is that these `Collection` implementations claim via the interface that they can be serializable, whereas in reality they can only be serializable if all elements they contain are also serializable, but their type parameter is not bounded with `Serializable`... Maybe they should have defined separately serializable implementations with bounded type parameters, and non-serializable implementations that accept any type of elements ^^'
That `Serializable` interface is definitely awkward!